# Azure Log analytics - access control to view only specific applications

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

We are currently using splunk to store the logs and planning to migrate to Azure and would be using log analytics. In splunk, application team will be granted access only to their logs however I don't know how can I grant access to the application support team to view only the specific set of logs on azure log analytics.

How do I manage access control to view only specific application logs in Azure log analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if a person or a group has access to only that particular resource and by default logging has been enabled to log analytics then those people will only be able to see logs for that particular resource. So as an example if I have access to an Azure SQL resource then I would go to that resource and would click on Logs from that resource's blade and view logs for it and same for metrics.

But for a detailed look on how to design permissions for Azure Monitor Logs then please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/design-logs-deployment) as to what i described above some caveats do exist.

Comment: In case of AKS where multiple applications are hosted on the same AKS Cluster, how do I ensure that specific logs are available only for the specific set of support engineers?

Comment: With AKS, you have two sets of people. One group is the people who are interested in Ops side of things by viewing Infra logs and then the second group of people who would like to view Application logs. For infra\ops people Azure Monitor for Containers with Logs should be enough & train them to view from the AKS resource blade and secondly the Developers; these people would not be interested in Infra stuff so for them you should enable Application Insights and make sure all the Application Logs go to it and they view all the application logs from the Application Insights resource itself.