# Azure DataFactory Log Analytics Access

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics

We have a Log Analytics workspace '`XYZ`' in one subscription where all azure services logs are being sent to, from all other subscriptions as well.

We have our Data Factory Solution in another subscription where one user has Owner access. Its logs are also being stored in '`XYZ`'.

The challenge we are facing is, this user wants to access Data Factory logs but we can't give it as the Log Analytics workspace contains logs from other services as well such as backup.

Is there a way to grant this user access only on Data Factory logs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Log analytics - access control to view only specific applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976173/azure-log-analytics-access-control-to-view-only-specific-applications)

Answer (score 0):

You can grant users and groups only the amount of access they need to work with monitoring data in a workspace by using role-based access control(RBAC). More detail, you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/manage-access).